# Show $Gl_3(\mathbb{F}_5)$ has a normal subgroup of index 4

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Show $Gl_3(\mathbb{F}_5)$ has a normal subgroup of index 4.
Here is my attempt: $|Gl_3(\mathbb{F}_5)|=(5^3-1)(5^3-5)(5^3-5^2)=124*120*100=1488000=2^7*3*5^3*31$. So I'm stuck.

Comment: Hint: Consider the determinant map $GL_3(\mathbb{F}_5) \to \mathbb{F}_5^*$.

Comment: Ok! The determinant map is a surjective homomorphism hence will have a no trivial kernel. And the kernel is of index 4. That's it right?

Comment: Yes, the kernel is $SL_3(\mathbb{F}_5)$.